# Year's Thumbnails into a wp_get_archives

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type

I have a custom post type called issue_number and I want to create archive page as this image here :

[image]

I want automatic thumbnail of the year

```
       <?php 
      $my_archives=wp_get_archives(array(

           'post_type'=>'issue_number', 
            'type'=>'yearly', 
            'format' => 'custom',


    'before' => '
    <h3 class="entry-title mh-loop-title archivio-anno-list">Table of 
      contents<br>
    ',

    'after' => '
    <br>
    <p>hello</p>

    <img src="<?php the_post_thumbnail_url(); ?>" alt="Mountain View" 
     style="width:33%;float:left;">
    <img src="" alt="Mountain View" style="width:33%;float:left;">
    <img src="" alt="Mountain View" style="width:33%;float:left;">
    <img src="" alt="Mountain View" style="width:33%;float:left;">
    <img src="" alt="Mountain View" style="width:33%;float:left;">
    <img src="" alt="Mountain View" style="width:33%;float:left;">


    <br></h3>',



'show_post_count'=>true, 
'limit'=>20, 



     ));

      print_r($my_archives); 



            ?>
```

This work but no the thumbnail...

Comment: That's really a confusing code... that `<?php the_post_thumbnail_url(); ?>` will not work at all. [**`wp_get_archives()`**](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_archives) expects simple parameters and you're feeding some heavy HTML on it. Not sure what the solution would be, but I think wp_get_archives alone won't do the job

Answer (score 0):

RESOLVED

I resolved the problem adding a new custom post type called ANNO and 1 relationship field called anno_issue from year to issue_number. The code is this for query :

```
<?php

 // args
    $args = array(
 ‘numberposts’  => -1,
 ‘post_type’    => ‘anno’,
  ‘posts_per_page’ => 100,
   );

 // query
    $the_query = new WP_Query( $args );

     ?>

            <?php while( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query-
         >the_post();
    mh_before_page_content();
    mh_magazine_page_title();?>

    <?php

    /*
   * Query posts for a relationship value.
        * This method uses the meta_query LIKE to match the string “123” 
to the database value a:1:{i:0;s:3:”123″;} (serialized array)
*/

$posts = get_posts(array(
  ‘post_type’ => ‘issue_number’, //nome post type da dove recupero le 
     info
     ‘posts_per_page’ => -1,
     ‘meta_query’ => array(
     array(
    ‘key’ => ‘anno_issue’, // nome custom field all’interno di post che mi 
    da 
 l’info
‘value’ => ‘”‘ . get_the_ID() . ‘”‘, // matches exaclty “123”, not just 
123. This prevents a match for “1234”
         ‘compare’ => ‘LIKE’
     )
     )
   ));

    ?>
  <?php /*ciclo stampa articoli */   ?>
    <?php if( $posts ): ?>

  <?php foreach( $posts as $post ): ?>
  <?php /*layout 1 del tema per articoli */    ?>
<article >

     —HTML CODE DISPLAYNG YOUR LOOP—
 </article>
    <?php /*fine layout 1 */    ?>
   <?php endforeach; ?>

  <?php endif; ?>

  <?php /*fine ciclo stampa articoli */ ?>

  <?php endwhile; // end of the loop. ?>
```